# vb.net application slow performance after installing on newly setup computers

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

i have been working on a project using Visual Studio 2015 along with vb.net and mysql. I deployed my application using ClickOnce to my company server then installed on all the computers in my company. It is working fine. Recently, i have it installed on three new computers which has the exact same os and specs with the existing computers, however, the application installed on the three new computers showed a very significant difference in performance comparing to the existing computers, it is much slower in the new computers.

I have checked through

> 1. the networks
> 2. the connection to MySql database
> 3. the memory it consumes
> 4. the .net framework version

but it is all exactly the same with the existing computers. does anyone have any idea what might be the cause? Or anyway to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just add timers, stopwatches, etc to instrumented builds. In fact, in an application of any size I build-in, from the off, at least a skeletal diagnostic system with a display window and stopwatches that can be used to time specific bits of code - typically database queries. With that in place, it's simple to add specifics to produce instrumented builds to drill down to any  problems that only occur on end-users' machines. You can also download DbgView from Microsoft and use that in conjunction with Trace statements in your code.

Comment: Okay I will try that . Thank you for helping